# How to delete rows in SQLite with multiple by where args using Anko?

Tags: android, kotlin, anko

I hope to delete a row by _id, I hope to delete multiple rows by where args using Anko too.

I have read the article at https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/wiki/Anko-SQLite#updating-values, but I have no result, could you help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, using the update method is wrong. Deleting is not the same as updating. Updating in SQL means changing the value of one or more fields in a row. What you are looking for is the [delete method](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/blob/e388295c70963d97d26820d4ecdf48ead8dba05e/anko/library/static/sqlite/src/Database.kt#L73)

```
dbHelper.delete(TABLE_NAME, whereClause="Your actual where statement here", args)
```

The where statement follows a slightly different syntax than the regular where clauses in SQLite. This is an exception to the update method because it has a method for "regular" SQL through a builder. The delete method does not have this though, so you have to use the Anko syntax.

Essentially you can use this as a where clause:

```
"someRow = {someRowData} AND differentRow = {otherData}"
```

and in the arguments:

```
"someRowData" to "whatever value you want",
"otherData" to 1234
```

I'm not entirely sure whether or not the `AND` keyword will work, the syntax isn't fully documented. I assume it should because there's nothing else documented. The general SQLite syntax should be valid, and only the argument replacement (to avoid SQL injection I assume) is different